# Apache2 returns php source code

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, apache2

Ubuntu 12.04

Apache2 is installed

```
# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar 19 2014 21:11:49
```

PHP is installed

```
# php --version
PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.8 (cli) (built: Apr  4 2014 01:28:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

PHP module is installed and enabled

```
# a2enmod php5
Module php5 already enabled
```

php5.conf contains SetHandler directive

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
        # Deny access to raw php sources by default
        # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
        # only in specific virtual host or directory
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml|ps)$">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

    # Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
    #
    # To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

but my file /var/www/wwwuser/data/domain.com/info.php

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

is not executed - it's source code returned. Why?

Comment: Look at [this](http://forums.devarticles.com/web-server-configuration-51/php-pages-won-t-load-show-source-code-apache-2t-52648.html) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/425181/php-code-is-returned-instead-of-executed). Hope they help.

Comment: @Idris I already googled it. No success.

Comment: Which URL do you use to access the file? Are there virtual hosts defined that may interfere with your module definition?

Comment: @TeTeT I use http://mydomain.com/info.php to access the file. Other vhosts exist by there are no collisions with them.

Answer (score 4):

Try sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.2 && sudo service apache2 restart
Well you might have another version of php, so refer to your php version. Worked for me zend run perfectly

Answer (score 3):

This question is a year old and it's probably too late for the OP, but there is no accepted answer and I stumbled here from Google. I was dealing with a very similar problem, and perhaps my solution will be of use to somebody in the future:

There is a PHP directive in `php.ini`:

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

If this is `Off`, then PHP will ignore `<? ?>` tags, as it requires `<?php ?>`.

So in my case, the problem was my test script:

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

Solution is to change the tags to `<?php` or just update the INI file to read `short_open_tag = On`.

Comment: This answer was a life saver, and I would never have thought of it. For context, they changed this from On to Off as the default between Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04

Comment: Please note, that it is highly discouraged to use short tags anymore as the RFC (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags_v2) is deprecating it in PHP 8.0 and will be dropped in PHP 9.0.